# [gdb][script] Syntax change from version 6.5 to 10.2 gdb gcc toolchain

Tags: gcc, gdb

The old syntax in the 6.5.0 that works for this statement:

```
set {int}(&FlashBufferStart+$EraseCnt*2+0) = 0x1000
```

This would mean placing value 0x1000 into into into the allocated address.

With the new 10.2.0 this sentence will result an error:

**Cannot perform pointer math on incomplete type "<data variable, no debug info>"**

I have tried using type casting parenthesis, {int} , {void*}, or value might just ended totally different, I have seen similar post for this error but it didn't solve the issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With the new 10.2.0 this sentence will result an error:

It appears that GDB doesn't know the type of `FlashBufferStart`.

GDB-6.5 probably assumed that this is a `char` (or maybe in `int`), and silently performed arithmetic corresponding to the assumed pointer type.

GDB=6.10 is telling you that it doesn't understand what you want it to do instead.

Solution: cast `&FlashBufferStart` to appropriate pointer type, so GDB knows what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I just change this into (int*) type as it work again!

Comment: @kaikaikai If the answer helped you, upvote it. If it completely answered your question, also accept it.